# Moving git from Server solaris 10 to solaris 11

Tags: git

I have git working on solaris 10, users home dirs are residing on an other file server (login wiht nis name server). I have new server solaris 11 with git installed, how can I migrate all repositories from old to new server ( users  use ssh to connect).

I tried new system (old systems ) same ip and name and tried to clone one repository, I got

error git clone ssh: connection timed out

Comment: If you can't use ssh, then Git certainly won't work. Fix ssh first.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix ssh first, obviously.

But, even when you get ssh working, I would recommend using `rsync` instead, something like this (execute on new server):

```
newserver$ rsync -av git@oldserver:/opt/repos/ /opt/repos/
```

This will make sure that new server has absolutely identical tree of all git repositories, including all branches, default heads and repository comments if you had any.

If you still insist on using `git clone`, be sure to use --mirror option. But even with this, you will have to painfully recreate whole tree - very time consuming and error-prone.

Comment: when I am login as user x,y etc my ssh is working fine, I can connect new server, how can I check config/ssh of git, I tried to check .gitconfig in git user (no file that), run git-config --list . can't see any details. For rsync, I have one user git, and running naming service, so if I  login old or new server, i am getting same home folder and repos

Comment: Well, instead of `git` user, you should use user name that owns all repositories. If repositories are owned by different users, this is quite a mess, and is better addressed by using key-based authentication git servers, like `gerrit` or `gitolite`